# What does "surety and scholar initial" mean

Tags: legal-terms

I have received an award letter of a scholarship which has terms and conditions to be printed on a non-legal stamp paper. There are 4 pages and at the end of each page there are the terms "Scholar Initial" and "Guarantor/Surety Initial" side by side with a short blank line above each, indicating that something needs to be written on it. What do they mean and what should be their purpose?

Answer (score 5):

It means that the scholar (presumably you) and the guarantor/surety should each write their [initials](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47934/what-are-initials) in that space, i.e. the first letters of their first and last names.  John Smith would write "JS".

This is a common way of acknowledging that you have read and understood the text on the page.

Comment: In the deed of the scholarship two witnesses are required which would agree that the scholat and guarantor gave their voluntary concent to the terms and conditions and signed on the deed. Is it legal that the Guarantor may be one of the witnesses ot is it necessary that the witnesses would be persons other than the scholar and guarantor?

Comment: @MShehzad I don't know which jurisdiction you're in, but in England and Wales a witness to a signature should be (or must be for some legal documents) neutral, independent and without any financial or other interest in the agreement being signed. Ergo, one cannot witness their own signature.

Comment: @RockApe Ok. That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

"Guarantor/Surety Initial" is typically an someone (specifically, an adult) who *guarantees* to pay money back if the terms of the contract are not met.

In your case of this scholarship, the people who offer the scholarship will probably want their money back if you drop out or flunk.

If you're a minor -- or even a young adult dependent on parents for tuition, etc -- then the Guarantor will most certainly be your parents.  If you're financially independent, then *you* might be the Guarantor.